# convert date column in a text file to float

Tags: datetime, numpy

I have a data file with the 2nd column in the file being dates in the format '01/01/2007'. I am trying to convert this column into number format so that I can insert the data in the textfile into a mysql database. I keep getting these errors when I try to do so:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/numpy", line 5, in <module>
    x = np.loadtxt(fname='xyz.txt', dtype=[('date', 'str', 12),('x','float')], converters={1:datestr2num}, delimiter=None, skiprows=0, usecols=None);
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 713, in loadtxt
    X.append(tuple([conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]))
  File "C:/Python27/numpy", line 4, in datestr2num
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(s,'"%m/%d/%y"')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '"01/01/2007"' does not match format '"%m/%d/%y"'
```

Can anyone please help me with this? Here is the code I am trying:

```
import numpy as np
import datetime
def datestr2num(s):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(s,'"%m/%d/%y"')
x = np.loadtxt(fname='xyz.txt', dtype= 'float', converters={1:datestr2num}, delimiter=None, skiprows=0, usecols=None);
print x;
```

Answer (score 2):

`'%y'` is for two-digit years (e.g. `'14'`); you have four-digit years (e.g. `'2014'`) so should be using `'%Y'` - see [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Comment: Thank you. I am really new to this whole thing. It helped but now I'm getting this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/numpy", line 5, in <module>
    x = np.loadtxt(fname='xyz.txt', dtype=[('date', 'str', 12),('x','float')], converters={1:datestr2num}, delimiter=None, skiprows=0, usecols=None);
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 731, in loadtxt
    X = np.array(X, dtype=dtype)
TypeError: expected a readable buffer object

Comment: @MiliReddy you should really look at http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html and, if that doesn't help, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist